# Using Visual Studio (not VS Code), with react without compiling each time

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I have created a project using this tutorial:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019#:~:text=%20Tutorial%3A%20Create%20a%20Node.js%20and%20React%20app,a%20Node.js%20web%20application%20project.%20Open...%20More%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=%20Tutorial%3A%20Create%20a%20Node.js%20and%20React%20app,a%20Node.js%20web%20application%20project.%20Open...%20More%20)

It is working perfect but, for each change I do to the code, I need to compile to see results.
Any way changing index.html, packacge.json or wathever to do an npm start and see results without compiling?

The current struct I have is an app.tsx file that is the main reactdom file and a lot of js files.
after compiling a dist\app-bundle.js file is created and is the file that is in the index.html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="./dist/app-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried to change src to "./app.tsx" to avoid generating app-bundle.js every time, but doesn't work. A blank page is what I have.

What I would like to have is the browser working over the source files and not over the compiled one to develop faster. And when finishing, then compile only one time.

I hope I explained more or less right.

thanks!
Thanks!

Comment: Run webpack in watch mode? Then it transpiles code on file changes instead of requiring you to do so manually.

Comment: ^ this, or better the dev server with hot module replacement

Answer (score 0):

From where i'm at right now, you do need to add more detail in your question about what you actually want. When you mean "compile" are you just referring to running your code at runtime using "npm start".

If so, with Node.js, any change you make to your source folder will not show up if you are already running your application. Although, there is a package you can download called Nodemon that allows you to make changes to your application and once saved, restarts your server with the new build in mind.

To install this for VS2019, navigate to your solution explorer, right click your npm, select "install new packages", search nodemon and install. Once installed, open your package.json file and under your scripts, modify your npm start script to stop running with node and instead run with nodemon :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to see changes in real time. the problem I have is that the source code are lot of files, the main one is app.tsx. but when I run npm start, it opens the "compiled" one that is dist\app-bundle.js...

so, if I edit source, the app-bundle.js don't change until I compile 
what I want is tell npm to use source files to run, and not compiled file.
I tried to change index.html pointing to app.tsx and not dist\app-bundle.js but I blank page is what I got.

I tried adding "npm start" entry but It isn't working.

Many thanks!

Comment: What i may think you want is to use ts-node to run your server in real time, without using the tsc compiler. Usually for any TS/JS node environment, you would run the server using ts-node and then once ready for production, compile with tsc and you get your bundled file ready. To install ts-node, enter "npm install -D ts-node" into your terminal and have a script in your package.json file called "dev": "ts-node index.ts". For nodemon support there is plenty of sources available for you to find out how to run nodemon with TypeScript. Good luck!

Comment: what I want is to use ts-node with the source code, and not with the compiled code. I want to avoid compiling each time I do any change while testing my code.